# Unexpected = (equal sign) characters in wp mail

Tags: wp-mail, encoding

I have created a custom form for user registration and a custom html email when someone registers.

```
$headers = 'From: test<ttest@test.org>' . "\r\n";
$subject = 'Test Subj';
$msg='';
$msg .= 'ATTN: '.$fname.'<br><br>';
$msg .= '<strong>*Please confirm receipt of this message. If you are not the intended recipient, please notify us immediately.*</strong><br><br>';
$msg .= 'The * is delighted to invite you to submit a formal grant proposal via our online form. Below you will find a link to the application and your customized username and password.
<br><br>';
$msg .= '<strong>Website Link:</strong> <a href="'.site_url().'/grant-application-form">'.site_url().'/grant-application-form</a><br><br>';
$msg .= '<strong>Username:</strong> '.$uname.'<br>';
$msg .= '<strong>Password:</strong> '.$pass .'<br><br>';
$msg .= 'If you received a grant last year, please be sure to also submit a formal grant update here:  <a href="'.site_url().'/grant-update-form">'.site_url().'/grant-update-form</a>. Failure to provide this report may disqualify your organization from future funding.<br><br>';
$msg .= '<strong>Please submit your application by the deadline specified in the online form.</strong><br><br>';
$msg .= 'The website will allow you to save your work as you go, review the application/ update before you submit, and upload documents such as your budget, 990-PFs, and 501(c)(3) Determination Letter.  Once you have submitted your application/ update, you will receive an email confirmation that we have received it. You will also be given the option to download a PDF copy of your submission.<br><br>';
$msg .= 'We look forward to reviewing your proposal.<br><br>';
$msg .= 'Best wishes,<br><br>';
$msg .= '<img src="'.site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo.png" width="200"/>';
wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers);
```

Everything is working fine but some users are complaining that they are having formatting issues.

[image: result]

Comment: Seems similar to this issue https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/211244/few-chars-getting-replaced-with-in-mail-content-in-wp-mail

Comment: Impossible to resolve based solely on the information provided.